# Get the most popular pages of user in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I get a list of the most visited current user's sites via chrome api?
I try to make custom speed dial page.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>RTFM</strike> See the API list at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

> Use the [`chrome.topSites` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/topSites) to access the top sites that are displayed on the new tab page.

Do note that Chrome will not provide thumbnails for the sites.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I decided to tone it down.

Comment: yeah it wasn't so nice ahah

Comment: chrome.topSites is giving me only 10 sites, can i get more?